# Lenskit documentation

Tags: lenskit

I'm trying to get the hang of Lenskit (quite hard at first). Right now I'm playing around with the hello-lenskit examples, it is working as expected. However, I'd like to go beyond that and when I read the documentation it seems it's not up to date, e.g.,

http://lenskit.org/documentation/basics/configuration/

(many links, such as the one for `LenskitRecommenderEngineFactory`, `ItemItemRatingPredictor` lead to `page not found`)

So, how did you experts get to master lenskit? trial and error? mailing list? here?

Cheers!!

Comment: Either the mailing list or specific questions on StackOverflow are probably the best means. The developers see mailing list questions quicker. I've gone and updated some of the egregiously out-of-date pieces of that page you referenced.

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing that up so quickly. I'll keep skimming through the documentation, and follow your advice if I get stuck.